# javascript innerhtml with javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, innerhtml

I am trying to write the date in a simple mm/dd/yyyy format. My script is:

```
test = new Date()
month = test.getMonth()
month = month + 1
day = test.getDate()
year = test.getFullYear()
document.getElementById("dateText").innerHTML = month;"/";day;"/";year
```

I got `document.write(month,"/",day,"/",year)` to work but I cannot get this to work. I would like to use my styled paragraph with a `<p>` tag, not the default type. I am putting it in the `<header>` in the body as follows:

```
<p id="dateText"></p>
```

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Javascript syntax; in particular, what `;` means.

Comment: Strings are concatenated with `+`.

Comment: Learn about [**string concatenation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators).

Comment: And you will need to wait for document ready or onload....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String concatenation in JavaScript is done using the `+` operator, not `;`.

```
document.getElementById("dateText").innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

Comment: Still going to error since that code is in the head.